# Помогите с познанием ORM

Tags: sql, python-3.x, orm

```py
class Field:
    def __init__(self, f_type, required=True, default=None):
        self.f_type = f_type
        self.required = required
        self.default = default

    def validate(self, value):
        if value is None and not self.required:
            return None
        return self.f_type(value)


class IntField(Field):
    def __init__(self, required=True, default=None):
        super().__init__(int, required, default)


class StringField(Field):
    def __init__(self, required=True, default=None):
        super().__init__(str, required, default)


class ModelMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace):
        if name == 'Model':
            return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)

        meta = namespace.get('Meta')
        if meta is None:
            raise ValueError('meta is none')
        if not hasattr(meta, 'table_name'):
            raise ValueError('table_name is empty')

        fields = {k: v for k, v in namespace.items()
                  if isinstance(v, Field)}
        namespace['_fields'] = fields
        namespace['_table_name'] = meta.table_name
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)


class Manage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model_cls = None

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if self.model_cls is None:
            self.model_cls = owner
        return self

    def create(self):
        print(self.model_cls)


class Model(metaclass=ModelMeta):
    class Meta:
        table_name = ''

    objects = Manage()

    def __init__(self, *_, **kwargs):
        for field_name, field in self._fields.items():
            value = field.validate(kwargs.get(field_name))
            setattr(self, field_name, value)


class User(Model):
    id = IntField()
    name = StringField()

    class Meta:
        table_name = ''


class Man(User):
    sex = StringField()

    class Meta:
        table_name = ''
```

Пытаюсь реализовать собственый ̶в̶е̶л̶о̶с̶и̶п̶е̶д̶ ORM, столкнулся с проблемой на старте и подозреваю, что это связано с mro. Почему у объекта класса Man не наследуются атрибуты класса User? И еще было бы неплохо, если бы кто-то посоветовал, где можно подсмотреть реализацию похожей задачи? Не советуйте исходники Django, ибо для меня сложно.

```py
>>> man = Man(id=1, name="Nikita", sex="male")
>>> man
<orm.Man object at 0x7fa89fa79c50>
>>> man.__dict__
{'sex': 'male'}
>>> man.id
<orm.IntField object at 0x7fa89f570898>
>>> man.name
<orm.StringField object at 0x7fa89f5708d0>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему добавлением такой строчки в описании метакласса:

```py
class ModelMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace):
        if name == 'Model':
            return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)

        meta = namespace.get('Meta')
        if meta is None:
            raise ValueError('meta is none')
        if not hasattr(meta, 'table_name'):
            raise ValueError('table_name is empty')

        #########################################################
        for base in bases:
            namespace.update(base.__dict__.get('_fields', []))
        #########################################################

        fields = {k: v for k, v in namespace.items()
                  if isinstance(v, Field)}
        namespace['_fields'] = fields
        namespace['_table_name'] = meta.table_name
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)
```